# Replacement for bullet-proofed

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I was suggested to use the term `bullet-proofed` by a colleague. Someone else now pointed out that `bullet-proofed` might not even exist, because we can't build the past tense of an adjective.

Part one of the question is: can `to bullet-proof` be a verb which describes "making something bullet-proof"? And in consequence `bullet-proofed` then means "having made something bullet-proof"?

So far, that's just for me, learning about it. I actually have decided to replace the word by something else.

The word is intended to be used like "a bullet-proofed solution", which is close to `foolproof` or `stable` or `tested`. However, I would not use `foolproof` as a term here, because it might sound offending in the business context it is used.

Can you think of the correct term my colleague might have had in mind when suggesting `bullet-proofed`? Note that we're both non-native English speakers.

Update:

@skymninge hit the definition. The intended use is like "not subject to correction, alteration, or modification", so I am looking for a synonym of that.

Comment: Perhaps an _airtight_ solution? Though I see nothing wrong with calling it a bulletproof solution, either.

Comment: Looking at the second definition of bulletproof here: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bulletproof I would not use the verb "to bulletproof" as you intend, because that implies altering something.

Comment: Just so you know, [by far the most likely replacement for ***bullet-proofed*** is actually ***bulletproof***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bullet-proofed%2Cbullet-proof%2Cbulletproof&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbullet%20-%20proofed%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbullet%20-%20proof%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbulletproof%3B%2Cc0). The hyphenated version ***bullet-proof*** looks a bit "dated" to me, but OP's past tense version looks positively *quaint* (or even *archaic*, except it never really was used much).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer part one, yes, bulletproof can be used as a verb, and so you can say "This and such was bulletproofed by Jimmy A." This is colloquial or informal, though. The adjective you were looking for I think was "bulletproof". Example: "Locking the keys inside the case is a bulletproof solution." This ordinarily means that the solution is perfect and nothing can alter or change it; it stems from the idea that not even bullets could penetrate or change such a solution -- it is THAT strong.

If you don't want to use bulletproof as an adjective, you might try: **perfect**, **complete**, **impregnable**, or **solid**.

Comment: Looked up your suggestions in a dictionary and also found `impeccable` or `blameless`. My stomach feeling says I should not use something with `blame` in my context.

Comment: With some more lookups in this direction I found `mature`. That's maybe no longer very similar to `bulletproof`, but my colleagues agree to use it.

Answer (score 2):

*Ironclad* fits the description perfectly I think

*Flawless* might apply, but it might throw a slight air of arrogance to the subject

Comment: Looked it up: deriving `shellproof` or `dead certain` from your suggestion would match better - at least when using it in German. Not sure for English, though.

Comment: Possibly @ThomasW. **shellproof** reads like a synonym for what you already have, **bulletproof** (they derive from the same underlying premise: impervious to projectile attack)

Answer (score 1):

> [**sure-fire**](http://universalium.academic.ru/45017/sure-fire) sure-fire or sure·fire (sho͝orʹfīrʹ) adj. Informal
>   Bound to be successful or perform as expected:
>
> a sure-fire solution to the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure how informal I should go. It should be a business document. Is `dead certain` less informal?

Comment: @ThomasW., formality is the least of concerns when there is so much politics in the use of words.  Dependent on the nature of your business, I'd avoid words associated with war, guns, bullets etc. but personally, I like the 'Ironclad' choice